# Vidyo token expiration time and force expiration

Tags: vidyo

Can a Vidyo token for a resource be generated so that it does not expire?

Is there a way to force a token to expire early?

Answer (score 0):

The Vidyo.io token always has an expiration period, there is no straight way to keep it alive forever. However, you can set 'expiresInSecs' value to be quite big. But, this is strongly not recommended by Vidyo, as token determines the time range for the user to be able to JOIN the call (meaning that if a token expires during the call, the user will not be disconnected).

Regarding force expiration - there is no way to do it.

Maybe, if you described your use case and why you need this, it would have been easier to suggest you something.